# Get height of Accordions open state while closed

Tags: jquery

I'm using jquery to expand the height of a parent div on click, based on the height of an absolutely positioned accordion. It must be absolutely positioned in this case.

Each accordion button has its own function and the height of the parent will be accordion title (button) + content and will change depending on which section of the accordion is open.

The problem is that in order to get the correct height dynamically I need to know the size of the content when in open state as the default closed state on document load is `height:0;`

```
$('.button').click(function(){

var accordionHeight =  $('.accordion-content').height();  //default closed state, height:0;

$('.parent').height(accordionHeight + $('.accordion-title').height());

});
```

Is there any way to determine the height of the accordion content in the open state without setting the open state as the default?

If you need more info please let me know.

Edit: Some more info

Imagine a parent div with two children. The accordion is one child and the other is will always be the same height as the accordion div in all states.

Edit2: Solved based on variation of @LouysPatriceBessette's solution.

```
//expand accordion
    $(".custom-accordion .panel-collapse").addClass("in");
//get height 
    var accordionContent = $('.custom-accordion').height();
//display height 
    console.log(accordionContent);
//collapse accordion   
    $(".custom-accordion .panel-collapse").removeClass("in");
//check we still have the correct height value   
    console.log(accordionContent , "Hello, world!");

    $('.custom-accordion .title').click(function(){  
        $('.sibling').height(accordionContent);
    });
```

Comment: hello, you only need to add height to the .accordion-content when it is in open state right? when i click each button?

Comment: @bellabelle yes that correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is pretty theorical here... Without the whole markup and context.

But I'm tempted to suggest you to set the accordion opened on load, just the time needed to get the height(s) you need in variable(s) for later use.

Then close the accordion until the user opens it on click.

While those "measurements", you could set the opacity to zero... If the opened accordion is visible a couple milliseconds and if this is ugly.

So steps by step:

1. Load the page with the accordion fully opened. Opacity = 0;
2. Take all measuments.
3. Close the accordion.
4. Restore opacity to 1... You could use fadeIn() to make it look intentional by "desing" ;)

Comment: It is definitely a solution I could use. You wouldn't be able to see anything if you set opacity:1 in a closed state would you?

Comment: I don't get the last question... But I would play with the opacity of the accordion container, just to make it invisible while measurements... So while it is opened when it should not. That is a couple milliseconds.

Comment: Solved based on this idea without the need for the opacity. Added code to original question, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Try my working [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/beljems/14hp0t7L/).

Might this is what you need. :) Hope this will help you.

Each content will show if a button is `clicked`.

Comment: Thanks but this isn't quite right. Imagine a parent with children, the accordion is one child and the other child is content that will always be the same height as the accordion in all states.